# CasperJS running unix shell commands

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to find a solution to run unix shell commands in CasperJS in synchronous mode.

I have seen exec-sync for node.js, but could never make it work for casper:

Sync-exec: http://davidwalsh.name/sync-exec

I intend to run some unix utilities through casperjs:

```
sed -e "1,1000d" file1 > file2 -> To copy the first 1000 lines from file1 to file2
wc -l filename -> To calculate the lines
```

Maybe someone has experience with this.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue in the following way, just in case someone requires it:

Running unix commands as per example:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/child_process-examples.js

As far as synchronization is concerned, I have wrapped the command execution under:

```
casper.then(function() {

});
```

and achieved synchronized execution this way.